# Table height property doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: html, css

I've got HTML structure like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>some content</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My wrapper style is like this :

```
.wrapper{
color: #444444;
    height: 165px;
    line-height: 135%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 270px;
}
```

and my table has only width defined along with some inherited styles :

```
.wrapper> table {
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

What I want to do is that my table consumes maximum height of parent element that is `.wrapper` whose height value is `165px` but for some reason table height is not decreasing.

My end goal was to set a `y-overflow` on wrapper so if table gets bigger that `.wrapper` that user can scroll, what am I missing here any hints?

When I change table height to be > then 190px, the table reacts it grows bigger, but if I change to smaller size i.e. 165px or any below 190px it doesn't seem to respond

Comment: You don't use any height property at all on the table. What is it that you expect to affect the height of the table?

Comment: Adding `height:100%` or any height doesn't change anything, that is why I am asking I don't know what to do next

Comment: Adding `height: 100%` does change the height of the table. See the demo in my answer below.

Comment: I hope that's not similar to your actual table. A single cell table isn't a very good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addig `height: 100%` to the table style does make it inherit the height from the parent element:

```
.wrapper> table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WDFa2/

Note: The height that the table inherits is the specificed height of the parent, i.e. `165px`, not the height including padding, i.e. `175px`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it `100%` high, give it `height: 100%`. Currently you don't specify the height at all.

Remember that tables tend to not obey all height rules. If the content doesn't fit, they may be a little stubborn. ;)

Comment: Adding `height:100%` or any height doesn't change anything